# How to make secure ajax call using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am new to ajax, In my website, I am calling Ajax, it will pass parameter and it will retrieve records from database based on parameter.

But I can see the complete url link on Inspect Element's network tab like below

```
Employee.aspx?userid=45
```

I check this stack overflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847377/how-to-secure-ajax-request-in-asp-net). I didn't get clear idea about it.

In some website they mention we can you **Token,Authenticate the user,use cookies**. But I don't understand how to use those things on my ajax code

Comment: May I know Why did I get my negative votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for this is not fixed it based on which approach you follow. The stack overflow link you provided pointing out the same thing about the link issue which you have right now. Any ways following are some possible approaches you can follow in order to prevent your URL visibility to end users

**1. Make use of unique keys/alias/ids**

In order to prevent your table's primary key to be directly revealed to the end user from the devtools you can have a user key column in your user table which have some random 4-6 digit unique code per user so to identify each of them and use these keys to communicate through URL or service calls instead of primary key itself. Same can be applied to any tables. Some people prefer username alias used in the URLs like employee name "John Marshal" can have URL like Employee.aspx?username=john-marshal

**2. Token based on authentication or Cookies**

This is where some learning is required. The basic idea behind it is the service which is called based on the URL will only be served to the authentic user which have the token or the cookie already present at the user's end. So in that way the call won't reveal any data it will simply return "403 Forbidden" or "401 Unauthorized" HTTP responses. And such URL will only exist on the pages which are accessible by authentic user. It means until and unless the user is logged in they can't get data from such URLs.

Still there are many ways to achieve this but these are all approaches which can be considered; you totally can't secure the requested URL its the approach which can.

Hope it helps